# Conditionally sort results in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Here are the tables that I'm working with. There is a User table that has some predefined columns ('name' in the example below) and an Extra Attributes table that used for making schema extension possible. The Extra Attributes table stores values for any new extended attributes as key-value pairs('title' and 'mobile' are the extra attributes in the example below) and the 'user' column is used for joining with the main User table. This arrangement generally works well for most operations, but I am not able to think of a way to sort on any of the extra attributes for the Users.

```
User Table:
---------------
id        name
============== 
1         jon  
2         harry


Extra attributes table:
--------------------------------
user   attr_key    attr_value
================================
1      title       engineer
1      mobile      111-2222-4444
2      title       manager
2      mobile      111-0000-5555


Result of joining the two tables above(few columns intentionally skipped):
--------------------------------------------
id        name     attr_key    attr_value
============================================
1         jon      title       engineer
1         jon      mobile      111-2222-4444
2         harry    title       manager
2         harry    mobile      111-0000-5555
```

I'm using hibernate for ORM. Here are the entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<ExtraAttributes> extraAttributes;

    public String getName() {}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<ExtraAttributes> getExtraAttributes() {}

    ... 
}

@Entity
public class ExtraAttribute {

    private Long id;
    private String attrKey;
    private String attrValue;
    private User user;

    ...

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public User getUser() {}

    ...
}
```

I want to be able to sort the results by attr_value corresponding to a specific attr_key, say 'title'. The problem is that if I order the results by attr_value then all the attr_values will be considered, while I want to order by only the attr_values that correspond to a specific attr_key - 'title'. I thought of ordering both by attr_key as well as attr_value but this doesn't seem to solve the problem either.